# Sobreescribir el método paint de un atributo JPanel

Tags: java, java-swing, clase-abstracta

Quisiera saber si se puede sobreescribir el método `paint()` de un JPanel que es un atributo de una clase que hereda de JFrame, ya que si sobreescribo en la misma clase, invocará al metodo `paint()` de el JFrame y no del JPanel.

Answer (score 2):

Evita sobrescribir el metodo paint y en su lugar usa paintComponent.

```
class Grafico extends JPanel{
    static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillRect(0,0, 50, 50);
    }

}
```

Para mas informacion sobre porque usar paintComponent sobre paint puedes revisar el siguiente enlace https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15103553/difference-between-paint-and-paintcomponent.